# Не идёт парсинг через BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Этот код должен парсить новости с сайта, но почему-то он выдаёт только статус о подключении и гасится. Не знаю в чём подвох. Помогите, пожалуйста)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.techcult.ru/technology'

page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code)

new_news = []
news = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
news = soup.findAll('a', class_='pad pad1 pad2')

for i in range(len(news)):
    if news[i].find('h2') is not None:
        new_news.append(news[i].text)

for i in range(len(new_news)):
    print(new_news[i])
```

Comment: Наверное, у вас `new_news` пустой, проверяли код до него? Мб у вас циклы не выполнились или условие в первом из них

Comment: new_news заполняется только во втором цикле после news, а условие должно выполняться, т.к. с другого сайта парсинг идёт, но мне как назло нужно именно с этого(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заметил, что без браузерного `User-Agent` сайт держит подключение без ответа.

А еще, все новости находятся в теге `a` с классом `pad`, поэтому проще всего описать это css-селектором: `a.pad`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/677491dffbfad1bcc55629ccd7a0c476a6a2e21b/html_parsing/www_techcult_ru__technology.py#L18)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
}

rs = requests.get('https://www.techcult.ru/technology', headers=headers)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, "html.parser")

for a in root.select('a.pad'):
    url = a['href']
    title = a.h2.get_text(strip=True)
    print(title, url)

# Фильтр из аэрогеля бесплатно и быстро очистит любые объемы воды https://www.techcult.ru/technology/8196-filtr-iz-aerogelya-bystro-ochishaet-lyubye-obemy-vody
# Система тросиков Wireality сделает виртуальные предметы реальными и осязаемыми https://www.techcult.ru/technology/8199-tehnologiya-wireality-delaet-virtualnye-predmety-realnymi
# Графен превосходно справился с защитой труб от бактериальной коррозии https://www.techcult.ru/technology/8193-grafen-zashishaet-truby-ot-bakterialnoj-korrozii
# Алмазные нанонити запасают энергию в три раза эффективнее Li-Ion батарей https://www.techcult.ru/technology/8194-nanoniti-zapasayut-energiyu-effektivnee-litij-ionnyh-batarej
# Искусственный интеллект Fujitsu справляется с управлением Токийским портом лучше людей https://www.techcult.ru/technology/8190-ii-spravlyaetsya-s-upravleniem-tokijskim-portom-luchshe-lyudej
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код + 1 импорт и замена двух строк

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.techcult.ru/technology'

page = requests.get(url)

print(page.status_code)

new_news = []
news = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

news = soup.findAll('a', class_=re.compile(r'pad\d?')) # меняем эту строчку вашего кода на ту что здесь

for i in range(len(news)):
    if news[i].find('h2') is not None:
        new_news.append(news[i].h2.text)   # news[i].text -> news[i].h2.text

for i in range(len(new_news)):
    print(new_news[i])
```